# Dynamic GET of a JSON object for MusicBrainz app | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I would like to add a search form to my small app.  But it has to send the result of the form to the link of the request.

I get artist's names from musicbrainz JSON database with the following request : http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query="NAME OF AN ARTIST"%20e*&fmt=json

Where "NAME OF AN ARTIST" is the name that I would like to post with a form.
I'm a bit new to angular sorry for the question if it's a bit stupid, cause I search all over the internet and I can't understand well.

Here is the form:

```
<form ng-submit="search()" name="nomartiste">
  <label>Rechercher:
    <input type="text" ng-model="nom"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Rechercher"></input>
  </label>
</form>
```

Here is the JS:

```
function Artiste($scope)
{    
    $scope.nom = 'Muse';
    $scope.search = function()
    {
        var url = "http://search.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=" + $scope.nom + "%20e*&fmt=json";

        $http.get(url)
            .then(function(response)
        {
            $scope.listenoms = response.data;
            console.log($scope.listenoms);
        })
    }
}
```

It should display result of the request with `$scope.nom` from the form as a parameter

I tend to add that nothing is displaying in the log console, even the Json tree :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the URL you provided, I received a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` response. Your browser's console might be hiding this for some reason if you're not seeing anything.

From their web service [documentation](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2/Search#Artist), you should use a URL like this to search for an artist: http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:Muse.

Note I changed this line: `$scope.listenoms = response.data.artists;`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.nom = "Muse";

  $scope.search = function() {
    var url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:" + $scope.nom + "&fmt=json";

    $http.get(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.listenoms = response.data.artists;
        console.log($scope.listenoms);
      });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <form ng-submit="search()" name="nomartiste">
    <label>Rechercher:
      <input type="text" ng-model="nom" />
      <input type="submit" value="Rechercher"></input>
    </label>
  </form>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Disambiguation</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="artist in listenoms">
        <td>{{artist.name}}</td>
        <td>{{artist.country}}</td>
        <td>{{artist.disambiguation}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, well I well understand that's well explained here, thank you ! Problem that I don't understand, here in the snippet its working, I mean : 

You write Muse 
=> you have list of artist begining by muse
=> you can erase the research by reasearching new artists
But on my computer in localhost, it just keep 'muse' as an artist in $scope.nom and it's not getting the "nom" from the form. I fixed the cross origin problem by adding a chrome extensions allowing CORS.

Comment: @MaximeBissonnier It sounds like `$scope.nom = 'Muse'` is being set everytime you call `search()`. Double-check that `$scope.nom` is definitely outside the search function. If that isn't it, check very carefully for spelling/syntax errors. If you copy paste my code and run it locally do you still get the error?

Comment: OH gosh ! It looks like it was just a small problem of the "ng-controller". I put it first on the <body> but I tried to put it to the global div, like here with Ionic : <ion-content> and it works ! I spent all this time for this small error .. ! At least I won't do it again. Thank you for all your explanations, have a nice coding day !

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you wish to display the result of running your queries. So you issued an http.get which returns a JSON object named response. But you then try to access data, which does not exist.

Remove 'data' from 'response.data'

Comment: $http.get(url)
            .then(function(response){
            $scope.listenoms = response;
            console.log($scope.listenoms);
        });

Nothing is happening, i just hit the submit button but nothing is displaying..

Comment: Are you including $http as a dependency? e.g. function Artiste($scope, $http) {}.. Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: @GrahamT Yes I have it in my controller .controller('artisteCtrl', function($http, $scope){..} and nothing in the console

Comment: Remove the Artiste function. Define the method bound to your form within the controller scope